# Try Again Button When Pressed Resets Everything But Everything Becomes Quicker

Tags: java, swing

So, I had a problem concerning a Try Again button that would show on Game Over screen and when clicked on reset everything to initial value. Now that problem is partially solved but every time I click on it everything becomes crazy fast and with each click faster and faster.

Here is my code from class which does initialization:

```
public class game extends JPanel implements ActionListener{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Menu menu;
private GameOver gameover;


//variables
public static int cyclesToWait = 50;
public static int enemiesKilled = 0;
public static int life = 3;
int roundCount = 0;
Timer gamelooptimer;

//objects
Player p;
ControllerEnemy c;
ControllerRocket r;
ControllerExplosion e;


//is it new round or not --> for enemy control
public static enum ROUND{
    INPROGRESS,
    NEW
}

public static enum STATE{
    MENU,
    GAME,
    OVER
};

public static STATE State = STATE.MENU;
public static ROUND Round = ROUND.INPROGRESS;

public game(){

    setFocusable(true);

    initGame();
}

public void resetGame(){
    initGame();
}

private void initGame(){
    enemiesKilled = 0;
    life = 3;
    roundCount = 0;
    gamelooptimer = new Timer(10, this);
    gamelooptimer.start();

    p = new Player(MainClass.width / 2 - 60, 400);
    c = new ControllerEnemy();
    r = new ControllerRocket();
    e = new ControllerExplosion();
    menu = new Menu();
    gameover = new GameOver();

    addKeyListener(new KeyInput(p));
    addMouseListener(new MouseInput());
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(getBackgroundImage(), 0, 0, null);

    Font fnt = new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 22);
    g.setFont(fnt);


    if(State == STATE.GAME){
        p.draw(g2d);
        c.draw(g2d);
        r.draw(g2d);
        e.draw(g2d);
        g.drawString("Round: " + roundCount, MainClass.width - 125, 22);
        g.drawString("Enemies Killed: " + enemiesKilled, MainClass.width/2 - 95, 22);
        if(cyclesToWait < 50)
            cyclesToWait++;
    }
    else if (State == STATE.OVER)
        gameover.render(g);
    else
        menu.render(g);


}



@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();
    if(State == STATE.GAME){    
        p.update();
        c.update();
        r.update();
    }
    if(Round == ROUND.NEW)
        roundCount += 1;
}
private Image getBackgroundImage(){
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Background.png"));
    return i.getImage();
}
```

resetGame() is called from another class.

Comment: Hint: do you really think you need to create a new `Timer` every time you reset the game? Do you think you need to add a new key listener or mouse listener?

Comment: Everytime you call `initGame()` a new `Timer` is started which also updates your game. So the first time you restart, your game is updated twice as much as normal per frame. The second time you restart, it's already thrice as much.